# While releasing react native app to the play store getting error, This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher

Tags: react-native, android-12

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#

[image]

I have added the property 'android:exported' to the AndroidManifest.xml. But the same issue occurs while uploading

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.domain.example">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     android:exported="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- You will also only need to add this uses-library tag -->
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: please add your AndroidMenifest code here

Comment: Manifest file added, Can you check what i missed ?

Comment: you don't need to add exported in application tag. only in activity tag is fine. everything else seems fine. try to clean cache/ build and rebuild the .aab file

Comment: Same error, I tried that too